# Static source file(.html) update does not working to application

Tags: jhipster

I am just a newbee to jhipster. finally I generated jhipster and runned an application. I tried to change static file(.html) for test.

- What I did as follows.

  1. I changed src/main/webapp/app/layouts/footer/footer.component.html file content.
     ('This is your footer'  --> 'This is your footer !!!!!')
  2. Executed command **yarn start**. Application running without problem.
  3. I found running application footer still' This is your footer'. But footer.component.html file content still 'This is your footer !!!!!'.
  4. I tried many times but application's footer still unchanged.
  5. I tried compile executing command **yo jhipster**.
  6. Terminal Ask overwriting footer.component.html file? so I typed 'y'
  7. After compile I checked footer.component.html file content. but it rolled back to the original file ('This is your footer'. not 'This is your footer !!!!!')

Please Teach me what I had missed. How can I change contents of static files.
This problem makes me crazy for last 2days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using i18n option? Which URL are you browsing? yo jhipster is not used for compiling your app, it's used to generate it.

Comment: @ganggaro, did you find my answer correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let us know if you installed any language while creating the project.

If yes then jhipster uses this following library for translations, so the actual String comes from a json file.

https://angular-translate.github.io/

You can do the following.

Instead of

```
 <div class="footer" ng-cloak>
            <p data-translate="footer">This is your footer</p>
 </div>
```

Try the following.

```
<div class="footer" ng-cloak>
            <p>This is your footer!!!</p>
 </div>
```

**Or a better option would be to change the json file.**

src/main/webapp/i18n/en/global.json

```
 "footer": "This is your footer"
```

to

```
 "footer": "This is your footer!!!"
```

Comment: Glad to know that Ganggaroo, please can you select the answer as correct. :)